# how to reduce the size of wp_postmeta and wp_post tables?

Tags: mysql, wordpress

My website was down a few days ago.
The domain name was purchased through siteground and the website was built using wordpress.
The notification is "database limited"
And I check MySQL, these two tables is in large size.
wp_postmeta:515MB
wp_post: 200MB
**how to reduce the size of wp_postmeta and wp_post tables?**
Or maybe are there any wrong operations when I post?
**I don't know how to safely clean and reduce the size of these two tables and what content are they storing.**

I try to delete some plugins in wordpress. And use the SG optimizer and WP optimizer.
The size of database Reduced by 100MB.
But I don't know what kind of contents are deleted.

**And as I keep posting, the two tables are being larger.**
**What should I do when Posting in order not to make these two tables larger?**
**Clear up these two tables to reduce the size**

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.